# Help with this trigonometric integral (why doesn't my method work)?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The definite integral, $$\int_0^{\pi}3\sin^2t\cos^4t\:dt$$

**My question**: for the trigonometric integral above the answer is $\frac{3\pi}{16}$. What I want to know is how can I compute these integrals easily. Is there more than one way to solve it? If so, is the key to solving these integrals, just recognizing some trig identities and using u-sub until it looks like a simpler integral?

**Here's what I tried (Why doesn't it work!):**

I rewrote the integrand as: $3(1-\cos^2t)\cos^4t\:dt$ then foiled it in,

$3\cos^4t-3\cos^6t dt$
, then I used the power rule and multipied through by chain rule and then did

$F(\pi)-F(0)$ and got the answer: $\frac{6}{35}$

Why does this not work?!?

Comment: I used the double angle identity for sin^2t and it looked even more difficult

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Could any method work as long as the rewritten integral matches the original integral? I find that if I use the wrong identity or substitution and try another one, it will be very tedious and waste time

Comment: @Jtheconstant, you need to add more detail if you want us to pinpoint where you went wrong. For example what does the antiderivative $F$ you got look like? What are your steps to get that $F$?

Comment: I don't know how to format it, and it will take too long to format it right now. Anyways, to get the antiderivative, I just raised the entire cos(t) to the power your see in the middle. I added 1 to that power and divided it over the constant '3' in front of it (using the power rule). Then I multiplied each cos by chain rule individually.

Comment: for example: 3(cost)^4 became 3/5 * (cost)^5 * -sint

Comment: and - 3 (cost)^6 became -3/7 * (cost)^7 * - sint. Then the integral is  ( 3/5 * (cost)^5 * -sint ) +  ( 3/5 * (cost)^5 * sint ) and I then plugged pi and 0 in

Comment: you have done mistake in using power rule .

Comment: how? isn't the rule for x^n: [ x^(n+1) ] / (n+1). The power in the middle of cos(t) can be moved to the front

Comment: @Jtheconstant: to apply power rule in the middle "cos" term you would need $d(cost)$ instead of $dt$ beside $cos^6 t$ - see it as $u =cost$ Since the variable of integration is $dt$ not $d(cost)$ so power rule can't directly applied without substitution

Comment: Use: $3 \sin ^2(t) \cos ^4(t)=\frac{3}{32} (2+\cos (2 t)-2 \cos (4 t)-\cos (6 t))$ ?

Comment: Did you use the double angle identity for sin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that can tackle more general problems of this nature.

First, let's consider the integral $I = \int \sin^2 x \cos^4 x dx$ (I just omitted the constant multiplier).

We can write $I = \int \sin x \cdot \sin x \cos^4 x dx$ and use integration by parts with $u = \sin x, dv = \int \sin^2 x \cos^4 x dx$ to get $I = \sin x \cdot (-\frac 15)\cos^5 x - \int\cos x \cdot (-\frac 15)\cos^5 xdx = \sin x \cdot (-\frac 15)\cos^5 x +\frac 15 \int\cos^6 xdx$

Applying the bounds, we get $I_{0}^{\pi} = \frac 15 \int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^6 xdx$

Now we're left with the problem of working out $J = \int \cos^6 xdx$

From Euler's identity and De Moivre's theorem (complex number theory), we can write $\cos x = \frac 12(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$. We also know that $\cos nx = \frac 12(e^{nix} + e^{-nix})$

Applying binomial theorem and the above, we can write $\cos^6x = (\frac 12(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}))^6= \frac 1{64}(e^{6ix} + 6e^{4ix} + 15e^{2ix} + 20 + 15e^{-2ix} + 6e^{-4ix} + e^{-6ix}) = \frac 1{64}(2\cos 6x + 12\cos 4x + 30\cos 2x + 20)$, and you can then compute $J = \frac 1{64}(\frac 13 \sin 6x + 3\sin 4x + 15\sin 2x + 20x) + c$, and after applying the bounds, you get $J_{0}^{\pi} = \frac {20\pi}{64} = \frac{5\pi}{16}$.

You can now compute $I_{0}^{\pi} = \frac 15 J_{0}^{\pi} = \frac{\pi}{16}$ and the original integral is $3I_{0}^{\pi} =\frac{3\pi}{16}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach $(1)$** 
Let
\begin{align}
y&=\cos t+i\sin t\implies y^n&=\cos t+i\sin nt\\
\frac{1}{y}&=\cos t-i\sin t\implies \frac{1}{y^n}&=\cos t-i\sin nt\\
\end{align}
Then 
\begin{align}
y+\frac{1}{y}=2\cos t \qquad y^n+\frac{1}{y^n}=2\cos nt\\
y-\frac{1}{y}=2i\sin t \qquad y^n+\frac{1}{y^n}=2i\sin nt\\
\end{align}
Now you can form your integrand using,
$(2i\sin t)^2=-4\sin^2t$
$(2\cos t)^4=16\cos^4t$ 
$$3\sin^2t\cos^4t=3\times\frac{1}{-4}\times\frac{1}{16}\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)^2\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^4$$
Now use [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement) and integrate term by term.
Why This approach is better?

> Polynomials are much easier to integrate

**Approach $(2)$**

Instead of convert the integrand into polynomial, you can convert it to exponential using [Euler formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry)

---

It seems you struggling with [$\int\cos^nt\:dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193435/565609). Don't use power rule here direction. You can use [reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#How_to_compute_the_integral) which came using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Comment: Why can't I use power rule? Oh, I know is it because chain rule is for 'derivatives' and not 'integrals'? I think this may be the error I made. If so, why can't I just multiply by the reciprocal of the expression that gets multiplied when using chain rule

Comment: Take a look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075108/565609) @Jtheconstant

Answer (score 2):

Use walli's formula given here to do it faster [Reduction formula for integral $\sin^m x \cos^n x$ with limits $0$ to $\pi/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833731/reduction-formula-for-integral-sinm-x-cosn-x-with-limits-0-to-pi-2)

$I=3\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^2t\cos^4t\ dt=6 \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^2t\cos^4t\ dt=6\times \dfrac{(2-1)(4-1)(4-3)}{6(6-2)(6-4)}\times \dfrac{\pi}{2}=\dfrac{3\pi}{16}$

**your mistake :** Use of Power rule in wrong way

we know,

$\displaystyle\int x^m \ dx=\dfrac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}+C$ but this is not analogous to

$3 \displaystyle\int \cos^6t\ dt\neq\dfrac{3}{7}cos^7t + C $ as you've written in comments.

but ,

$\displaystyle\int \cos^6t\ d(cost)\ =-\displaystyle\int \cos^6t \ sint\ dt \ =\dfrac{3}{7}cos^7t + C $

Answer (score 2):

**Note**  :-The  solution is specifically for the problem in question

The given function is **even**

So let $$I = 3\int_0^{\pi} \sin^{2}t \cos^{4}t dt$$
And it is equal to 
$$I = 6\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2}t \cos^{4}t dt\tag{1}$$

Now, we know that
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(b+a-x) dx$$

Therefore
We write the integral as
$$I = 6\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) \cos^{4}(\frac{\pi}{2}-t) $$

That is equal to
$$I = 6\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2}t  \sin^{4}t dt\tag{2}$$

adding equation (1) and (2) 
we get
 $$2I =6 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2}t \cos^{4}t + \cos^{2}t \sin^{4}t dt$$
Further
$$2I = 6\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2}t \sin^{2}t[\sin^{2}t+\cos^{2}t] $$
$$I = 3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2}t \cos^{2}t dt$$
$$I = \frac{3}{4} \int_0^{\pi/2} (2\cos t \sin t)^2 dt $$

Integrating,
$$I = \frac{3}{4} [( \frac{\pi}{4})-(\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2})]$$

So,

$$I= \frac {3\pi}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\frac{1+\cos\left(ax\right)}{2}=\cos^{2}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)$$

Then we have:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}3\cos^{4}\left(t\right)dt-\int_{0}^{\pi}3\cos^{6}\left(t\right)dt=\frac{3}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(1+\cos\left(2t\right)\right)^{2}dt-\frac{3}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(1+\cos\left(2t\right)\right)^{3}dt$$

Can you take it from here?

Or using reduction formula for $\int_{0}^{\pi}3\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)^{4}dx$ follows:

$$=3\left(\frac{1}{4}\cos^{3}\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)\Big|_0^\pi+\frac{3}{4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^{2}\left(x\right)dx)\right)$$$$=3\left(\frac{3}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi}1+\cos\left(2x\right)dx\right)$$$$=\frac{9\pi}{8}$$

Use this for the other one.

Comment: The answer is 3π/16

Comment: Can any substitution I make or identity I use work as long as the rewritten integrand matches the original one? What is the trick to solve these integrals?

Answer (score 0):

I see $2$ quick methods. Firstly, one could use $\sin t\cos t=\frac12\sin2t$ and $\cos^2t=\frac12(1+\cos2t)$ to get
$$\int_0^{\pi}3\sin^2t\cos^4t\,dt=\frac38\int_0^{\pi}\left(\sin^22t+\sin^22t\cos2t\right)dt$$
The period of $\sin2t$ and $\cos2t$ is $\pi$ so the integral is the average value of the integrand times the length of the interval. Now $\langle\sin^22t\rangle=\langle\cos^22t\rangle=\frac12\langle\sin^22t+\cos^22t\rangle=\frac12\langle1\rangle=\frac12$ and $\langle\sin^22t\cos2t\rangle=0$ because it has on odd power of $\cos2t$ so
$$\int_0^{\pi}3\sin^2t\cos^4t\,dt=\frac38\pi\left(\frac12+0\right)=\frac3{16}$$
The other easy approach is via the Beta and Gamma functions, but it's a little higher level math:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi}3\sin^2t\cos^4t\,dt&=3\times2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2t\cos^4t\,dt=3\operatorname{B}\left(\frac32,\frac52\right)\\
&=3\frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac32\right)\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac52\right)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(4\right)}=3\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac12\right)\sqrt{\pi}\left(\frac12\right)\left(\frac32\right)}{3!}=\frac{3\pi}{16}\end{align}$$